# How to set some views' center in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I can't do someView.center in mac app! How do I set my view's center similar to a iOS view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppKit works differently from UIKit—the “center” property isn’t a thing there. You’ll need to calculate the appropriate frame for your view yourself.

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(someX, someY);
CGSize viewSize = [myView bounds].size;
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(center.x - viewSize.width / 2, center.y - viewSize.height / 2, viewSize.width, viewSize.height)];
```

Answer (score 1):

center is available in NSWindow class,[window center],If the view exist as Window's subview,then he can use [[someview superview] center] or else he should go for manual calculations to set the center for his customized view as mentioned in above answer.